# increase height of accordion

Tags: html, css, accordion

I'd like to know what is the best way to add overall height to the accordion example in the link below.

I would like to make the `ul` sub-menu class taller, I would want the extra space to show as just empty with no list elements.

http://vtimbuc.net/gallery/pure-css3-accordion-menu-tutorial/

I think it is possible by adding another tag like a div around the `ul`, but I am wondering if there's an easier way in CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.accordion li:target > .sub-menu {
    min-height: 908px; //add your height here
    background: red; //add a background color what you would like 
    }
```

i made this

```
  min-height: 908px;
```

just for an example

Comment: is it possible to use percentage for height? Or would that require another approach?

Comment: yes its possible but requires a nother approach

Comment: could you elaborate on the approach, my layout if fluid I would need the min-height but would always want the entire accordion to take up a certain part of the browser screen?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't increase the size of the `ul` sub-menu class, rather each individual `a` tag.

Like so:

```
.accordion li > a {
  height: 64px; // was 32px;
}
```

This would double the height of each `a` tag, in turn increasing the height of `li` and ultimately the `ul`

Comment: Use padding, not height. Or maybe min-height. Otherwise you're stuck if you want to "zoom text" or if a link occupies 2 lines.

Comment: @FelipeAls While I agree, this particular dropdown seems to use height to determine the size, with 0 padding/margin on the `li`